# lxc create says options not valid

Tags: linux, lxc

I'm trying to create a container with lxc-create (v2.0.5). I don't have gpg installed and don't wish to install it (embedded system, no GPLv3). I've tried the `--no-validate` option but lxc-create says it does not exist, but it shows it as an option in the help printout. Any ideas?

```
# lxc-create -t download -n main  --no-validate
lxc-create: unrecognized option '--no-validate'
Usage: lxc-create --name=NAME --template=TEMPLATE [OPTION...]

lxc-create creates a container

Options :
 -n, --name=NAME               NAME of the container
 -f, --config=CONFIG           Initial configuration file
 -t, --template=TEMPLATE       Template to use to setup container
 -B, --bdev=BDEV               Backing store type to use
     --dir=DIR                 Place rootfs directory under DIR


Mandatory or optional arguments to long options are also mandatory or optional
for any corresponding short options.

See the lxc-create man page for further information.

LXC container image downloader

Optional arguments:
[ --variant <variant> ]: Variant of the image (default: "default")
[ --server <server> ]: Image server (default: "images.linuxcontainers.org")
[ --keyid <keyid> ]: GPG keyid (default: 0x...)
[ --keyserver <keyserver> ]: GPG keyserver to use
[ --no-validate ]: Disable GPG validation (not recommended)
[ --flush-cache ]: Flush the local copy (if present)
[ --force-cache ]: Force the use of the local copy even if expired
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"--no-validate" is not an option of "lxc-create" but an option of the "download" template.

"download" template options must be specified after "--" :

```
lxc-create -t download -n main -- --no-validate
```